# How to achieve group by in loop not using IList.GroupBy Method?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var type in types)
{
    BaseType existing = myOrderdList.Find(x => x.Id == type.Id);
    if (existing == null)
    {
        myOrderdList.Add(type);
    }
    else
    {
        type.BaseProducts.Add(existing.BaseProducts[0]);
        myOrderdList.Add(type);
    }
}
```

I have a list of `BaseType` class. And each `BaseType` has a list of `BaseProducts` IList.

Here are my clases :

```
public class BaseProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my BaseType Class :

```
 public class BaseType
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string CatalogName { get; set; }
     public List<BaseProduct> BaseProducts { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a Stored Procudre that will return a records like this :

```
Id  Name                ProductName                                Price

7   Digital Cameras 35  Sony DSCWX350 Digital Camera Black          600 
7   Digital Cameras 36  Sony DSCH400 Digital Camera Black           600 
8   Mobiles 15          Samsung Galaxy S4 VE GTI9515 Black 4G LTE   600 
8   Mobiles 16          Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo Dual Sim            600 
8   Mobiles 17          Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo Duos Smarthphone  600
```

Now my service method will create an object of basetype for each row.

So it will return a list of basetype.

How can I group the result by Name Not using IList.GroupBy Method ?

So Far I got this :

```
var types = ReadFromTheServiceMethd();
List<BaseType> myOrderdList = new List<BaseType>();
foreach (var type in types)
{
    BaseType existing = myOrderdList.Find(x => x.Id == type.Id);
    if (existing == null)
    {
        myOrderdList.Add(type);
    }
    else
    {
        type.BaseProducts.Add(existing.BaseProducts[0]);
        myOrderdList.Add(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need sorting instead of grouping or which data type are you willing to return?

Comment: No I need grouping, so I end up having only two BaseType objects instead of five. One for mobiles and one for Digital Cameras.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `GroupBy`? Because software development is not about reinventing the wheel.

Comment: One way is to implement some API like AddProduct(name categoryName, BaseProduct product) which will add product to the right place. Then you just add all products one by one.

Comment: You are right, I tried using group by I and got stuck in retrieving anonymous object in the Tresult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this would be to have a `Dictionary<int, BaseType>`, where `int` is the `Id` of the `BaseType`. With this in mind, if you're able to also return the `Id` for the `Name` field when executing your stored procedure, you could do this:

```
var products = ReadFromTheServiceMethd();
Dictionary<int, BaseType> baseTypes = new Dictionary<int, BaseType>();
foreach (var product in products)
{
    if (!baseTypes.ContainsKey(product.NameIdFieldHere))
    {
        BaseType newBaseType = new BaseType();
        // set the other properties here...
        baseTypes[product.NameIdFieldHere] = newBaseType;
    }

    baseTypes[product.NameIdFieldHere].BaseProducts.Add(product);
}
```